# very tall cell in UITableView cause very slow scroll performance

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a very tall cell with massive text content in it. [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) shows it's height is **7000+**. When scroll during that cell(it's so tall that will take a while) the tableView's scroll performance is particularly bad.

After *Time profiler* the tableView scroll. It shows the `drawRect:` method of one of subviews cost the most. That subview is a third party custom [textView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SECoreTextView). I breakpoint the `drawRect:` method the backtrace like so:
[image]

And it turns out the `drawRect:` is called many times when scroll during that very tall cell. So what cause the `drawRect:` is called during scroll inside one cell??

Comment: Check the implementation of cell reuseIdentifier working properly. If you are not reusing cell performance will be very slow when scrolling due to creation of new cell for each row of table.

Comment: checked cells are reused

Comment: If possible provide the implementation of cell code

Comment: Having a quick look at the custom text view you linked, it looks like `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` is called whenever the text view `frame` or `bounds` is set, and on touch events. In your situation, I would set a breakpoint in `-[SETextView setNeedsDisplayInRect:]` and look at the stack trace to find out where this is being called as you scroll. Let me know what you find!

Comment: @stefandouganhyde you are right! It is the `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` in touch related method that trigger `drawRect:` . please add a answer I will mark as accepted

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Thought it would be the touch events. Will add answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a quick look at the custom [text view](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SECoreTextView) you linked, it looks like `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` is called whenever the text view frame or bounds is set, and on touch events.

Looks it's the `UIResponder` touch methods that are the culprit, in which case setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on the `SETextView` should solve the problem. Of course, you may well want to keep interactions enabled on the text view, but I'm sure you can come up with something!

Comment: I choose to remove setneedsdisplayinrect there's too many of it